# List of Maps groupBy or collect

Tags: groovy

Okay so I have this list of Maps:

```
List data = [
    [name: "John", age: 21, gender: "male", option1: "test", option2: "test2"],
    [name: "Doe", age: 23, gender: "male", option1: "", option2: "test2"],
    [name: "Kate", age: 25, gender: "female", option1: "test", option2: ""],
    [name: "Ann", age: 22, gender: "female", option1: "", option2: ""]
]
```

So I want them to be grouped like this:

```
Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>()
    data.put("1", ["ID", "name", "age", "gender","option1", "option2"])
    data.put("2", [1, "John", 21, "male", "test", "test2"])
    data.put("3", [2, "Doe", 23, "male", "", "test2"])
    data.put("4", [3, "Kate", 25, "female", "test", ""])
    data.put("5", [4, "Ann", 21, "female", "", ""])
```

Or something that will look like this because I will insert this in a excel file. Or if anyone could recommend a good way to do this in groovy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the basic idea would be to create a new `TreeMap` (because you mentioned it, but I think a `LinkedHashMap` should be enough), put your *header line* there and then all the entries from your input list, with shifted indices.

One more tip, if you don't need [GStrings](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html), then use single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`)

Here, I took a little time and did it due to long-time no grooving and I miss this great language a bit:

```
List data = [     [name: "John", age: 21, gender: "male", option1: "test", option2: "test2"],     [name: "Doe", age: 23, gender: "male", option1: "", option2: "test2"],     [name: "Kate", age: 25, gender: "female", option1: "test", option2: ""],     [name: "Ann", age: 22, gender: "female", option1: "", option2: ""] ]

def exportData = [ 1 : [ 'ID', 'name', 'age', 'gender', 'option1', 'option2' ] ] as TreeMap

data.eachWithIndex { it, index  -> exportData.put(index+2, [index+1]+it.values())  }

println exportData​
```

**Try it [here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5154698147397632).**

Comment: Thanks you so much! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Because spreadsheets are a collection of cells, each having a column and row, one option is to prepare the data as a list of cells. Here's a working demo of how to do this:

```
@Grab('net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12')

import jxl.Workbook
import jxl.write.WritableCell
import jxl.write.Label
import jxl.write.Number as NumericCell

List data = [
    [name: "John", age: 21, gender: "male", option1: "test", option2: "test2"],
    [name: "Doe", age: 23, gender: "male", option1: "", option2: "test2"],
    [name: "Kate", age: 25, gender: "female", option1: "test", option2: ""],
    [name: "Ann", age: 22, gender: "female", option1: "", option2: ""]
]

new FileOutputStream(new File('test.xls')).withStream {stream ->
    def workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(stream)
    def sheet = workbook.createSheet('sheet name goes here', 0)
    def cells = []

    // Create the header cells
    use(ExcelWritableCellCategory) {
        ['ID', 'name', 'age', 'gender', 'option1', 'option2'].eachWithIndex {name, column ->
            cells << name.toCell(column, 0)
        }
    }

    // Create the data cells
    data.eachWithIndex {map, index ->
        def row = index + 1

        use(ExcelWritableCellCategory) {
             cells << row.toCell(0, row)

            ['name', 'age', 'gender', 'option1', 'option2'].eachWithIndex {key, column ->
                cells << map[key].toCell(column + 1, row)
            }
        }
    }

    // Put the cells into the sheet
    cells.each { sheet.addCell it }    
    workbook.write()
    workbook.close()
}

class ExcelWritableCellCategory {
    static WritableCell toCell(Number number, int column, int row) {
        new NumericCell(column, row, number.toDouble())
    }

    static WritableCell toCell(String string, int column, int row) {
        new Label(column, row, string)
    }    
}
```

Hint: I just noticed some redundancy in the list of keys; but that's an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create a list of lists, prepended with the header names:

```
List data = [
    [name: "John", age: 21, gender: "male", option1: "test", option2: "test2"],
    [name: "Doe", age: 23, gender: "male", option1: "", option2: "test2"],
    [name: "Kate", age: 25, gender: "female", option1: "test", option2: ""],
    [name: "Ann", age: 22, gender: "female", option1: "", option2: ""]
]

List result = data[0].keySet().with { keys ->
    data.inject([keys.toList()]) { curr, next ->
        curr << keys.collect { next[it] }
    }
}

assert result == [
    ['name', 'age', 'gender', 'option1', 'option2'],
    ['John',  21,   'male',   'test',    'test2'  ],
    ['Doe',   23,   'male',   '',        'test2'  ],
    ['Kate',  25,   'female', 'test',    ''       ],
    ['Ann',   22,   'female', '',        ''       ]
]
```